# JAVA MongoDB query to select distinct group of fields

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection named "valuesCollection" whose fields are :
`_id`, `cname`, `pname`, `timestamp`, `value`

In SQL, the query I would do is:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(pname, cname) 
    FROM valuesCollection
        WHERE (timestamp >= fromValue and timeStamp <= toDate)
        GROUP BY cname, pname
```

For MongoDB in my Java code, I wrote :

```java
    AggregateIterable<Document> parameters = valuesCollection.aggregate(
                Arrays.asList(
                    Aggregates.match(Filters.gte(MongoDBConstants.ROW_TIMESTAMP, fromDate)),
                    Aggregates.match(Filters.lte(MongoDBConstants.ROW_TIMESTAMP, toDate)),
                    Aggregates.group(MongoDBConstants.ROW_CNAME),
                    Aggregates.group(MongoDBConstants.ROW_PNAME)
                )
            );
```

But the result is empty.
What is wrong in my MongoDB query ?
Thanks a lot for your help!